# Extract JSON TypeMismatch Error Message

Tags: java, android, json

I was having some problem when trying to extract data from JSON. Basically, this is my JSON format:

http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/route/solve?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&routeStops=18304.68,36152.73;27985.4,34115&routemode=DRIVE&avoidERP=0&routeOption=shortest

And here is the codes:

```
public void getDirection(Event eventModel){
    String eventX = eventModel.getEventX();
    Log.i("X", eventX);

    String eventY = eventModel.getEventY();
    Log.i("Y", eventY);

    SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(
            Color.GREEN, 3, SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE.DASH);
    List pointArr = null;
    String page;
    JSONArray jsonArray;

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/route/solve?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&routeStops=18304.68,36152.73;" + eventX + "," + eventY + "&routemode=DRIVE&avoidERP=0&routeOption=shortes");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
        page = responseString ;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(page);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
            Log.i("Array", jsonArray.toString());
            JSONObject features = jsonArray.getJSONObject(3);
            //String geometry = features.getString("geometry");
            JSONArray paths = features.getJSONArray("paths");
            int length = paths.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                JSONObject attribute = paths.getJSONObject(i);
                    String path = attribute.getString("paths");
                    pointArr.add(path);
                    /*path = path.replace("[[\"", "");
                    path = path.replace("\"]]", "");
                    String[] arr = path.split(";");
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                        String[] point = arr[j].split(",");
                        pointArr.add(point);
                    }*/

            }
            Graphic lineGraphic = new Graphic((Geometry) pointArr, lineSymbol);
            graphicsLayer.addGraphic(lineGraphic);  
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, I am getting typeMismatch error message as the LogCat:

```
11-24 22:42:23.635: D/dalvikvm(4206): GC_CONCURRENT freed 627K, 12% free 11998K/13575K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-24 22:42:23.675: W/System.err(4206): org.json.JSONException: Value {"features":[{"geometry":{"paths":[[[18301.44000000041,36146.919999999925],[18885.830000000075,35820.75999999978],[19550.639999999665,35448.38000000082],[19679.16000000015,35397.5700000003],[19731.700000000186,35383.86999999918],[19799.240000000224,35381.169999999925],[19812.37999999989,35385.49000000022],[19828.570000000298,35394.31000000052],[19856.860000000335,35412.300000000745],[19875.230000000447,35468.13000000082],[19885.419999999925,35519.13000000082],[19887.83999999985,35531.25999999978],[19924.03000000026,35530.199999999255],[20053.900000000373,35572.88000000082],[20071.599999999627,35586.460000000894],[20078.78000000026,35595.31000000052],[20088.94000000041,35614.65000000037],[20111.830000000075,35668.51999999955],[20124.389999999665,35682.72000000067],[20145.12999999989,35697.40000000037],[20171.889999999665,35706.49000000022],[20229.700000000186,35708.38000000082],[20254.44000000041,35712.52999999933],[20308.200000000186,35726.9299999997],[20361.94000000041,35748.6799999997],[20371.480000000447,35751.43999999948],[20381.28000000026,35752.33999999985],[20496.959999999963,35762.949999999255],[20558.75,35763.08999999985],[20617.179999999702,35757.47000000067],[20723.37999999989,35739.27999999933],[20755.53000000026,35741.210000000894],[20802.16000000015,35760.75],[20853.950000000186,35794.74000000022],[20909.53000000026,35818.99000000022],[20935.05999999959,35828.8200000003],[20991.87999999989,35839.109999999404],[21014.44000000041,35846.91000000015],[21035.929999999702,35858],[21113.44000000041,35885.74000000022],[21161.209999999963,35914.98000000045],[21167.639999999665,35908.5],[21193.66000000015,35882.289999999106],[21206.96999999974,35871.199999999255],[21214.040000000037,35865.31000000052],[21221.080000000075,35861.22000000067],[21255.269999999553,35841.330000000075],[21270.78000000026,35838.24000000022],[21348.799999999814,35829.50999999978],[21376.360000000335,35828.52999999933],[21391.58999999985,35827.98000000045],[21419.820000000298,35826.98000000045],[21429.179999999702,35826.640000000596],[21437.96999999974,35826.330000000075],[21462.459999999963,35825.449999999255],[21594.21999999974,35822.75999999978],[21615.230000000447,35823.02999999933],[21644.009999999776,35826.50999999978],[21665.08999999985,35835.580000000075],[21703.19000000041,35857.4299999997],[21733.599999999627,35890.11999999918],[21775.389999999665,35945.84999999963],[21793.290000000037,35971.830000000075],[21810.580000000075,35996.539999999106],[21829.040000000037,36021.0700000003],[21848.650000000373,35997.11999999918],[21877.200000000186,35954.09999999963],[21950.490000000224,35865.90000000037],[21967.570000000298,35841.419999999925],[21997.03000000026,35789.26999999955],[22010.419999999925,35746.449999999255],[22011.799999999814,35714.11999999918],[22009.5,35679.16000000015],[21998.87999999989,35639.90000000037],[21986.639999999665,35606.86999999918],[21978.55999999959,35585.0700000003],[21979.12999999989,35568.11999999918],[21987.16000000015,35547.419999999925],[21998.05999999959,35533.59999999963],[22010.80999999959,35519.83999999985],[22178.459999999963,35460.65000000037],[22203.580000000075,35454.00999999978],[22368.80999999959,35396.36999999918],[22439.62999999989,35370.25],[22462.429999999702,35363.06000000052],[22536.71999999974,35337.8200000003],[22663.389999999665,35296.06000000052],[22783.040000000037,35254.419999999925],[22872.87000000011,35223.460000000894],[22905.179999999702,35212.34999999963],[22966.46999999974,35191.27999999933],[23098.830000000075,35146.419999999925],[23177.959999999963,35119.49000000022],[23298.53000000026,35078.460000000894],[23655.519999999553,34952.699999999255],[23677.139999999665,34945.109999999404],[23841.41000000015,34887.9299999997],[23862.490000000224,34880.550000000745],[23887.480000000447,34871.83999999985],[24026.480000000447,34822.210000000894],[24033.759999999776,34819.710000000894],[24057.400000000373,34811.580000000075],[24099.049999999814,34797.210000000894],[24120.46999999974,34789.9299999997],[24235.62999999989,3475
11-24 22:42:24.128: W/System.err(4206):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
11-24 22:42:24.128: W/System.err(4206):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
11-24 22:42:24.128: W/System.err(4206):     at Controller.EventController.getDirection(EventController.java:222)
11-24 22:42:24.128: W/System.err(4206):     at AsyncTask.GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.java:21)
11-24 22:42:24.128: W/System.err(4206):     at AsyncTask.GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.java:1)
11-24 22:42:24.135: W/System.err(4206):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-24 22:42:24.135: W/System.err(4206):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-24 22:42:24.135: W/System.err(4206):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-24 22:42:24.135: W/System.err(4206):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-24 22:42:24.135: W/System.err(4206):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-24 22:42:24.135: W/System.err(4206):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-24 22:42:24.135: W/System.err(4206):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(page);
            /*JSONObject myObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("routes");
            JSONArray features = jsonArray.getJSONArray(3);*/
            JSONObject geometry = jsonObject.getJSONObject("geometry");
            jsonArray = geometry.getJSONArray("paths");
            int length = geometry.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                JSONObject attribute = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String path = attribute.getString("paths");
                    path = path.replace("[[\"", "");
                    path = path.replace("\"]]", "");
                    String[] arr = path.split(";");
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                        String[] point = arr[j].split(",");
                        pointArr.add(point);
                    }

            }
```

Comment: I have a hunch you are calling the wrong data type on your json. Meaning you are asking for an object when its a string, or an array, etc. Whats at line 100?

Comment: @Jawascript the problem is not even in line 100... The problem is on line 222 of EventController. And that's because you're trying to create an array from what seems to be an object

Comment: Line 222 is this line: jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes"); which I tried to print out using the Log but it does not even shown up

Comment: Line 222 is this line: jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes"); which I tried to print out using the Log but it does not even show up

Comment: Down voter please explain :)

Answer (score 1):

"routes" is an object and not an array.

```
JSONObject myObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("routes");
```

Comment: But if I changed it to JSONObject, then how should I modify the portion below which interlined with it?

Comment: Simply replace what says `jsonArray` for `myObject`

Comment: Could you help me check if my geometry was JSONObject or array? And if I do this: JSONObject features = jsonObject.getJSONObject("features");, I am getting "No value for feature error message"

Comment: `geometry` is an object. `paths` is an array.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What? I just told you what your problem is. And you're asking if I have any ideas? I don't understand. You're trying to create an array of routes. When your "routes" is an object.

Comment: It's in the previous comment. If I followed like what you've suggested to replace jsonArray to myObject, the feature that line is getting that error message.

Comment: That's because features is an array and not an object. You don't seem to understand how JSON works. Parse your json here and this should help you understanding what is an array and an object. http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: @PedroOliverira Check my edited portion. I've modified it but I am getting no value for geometry error message now

Comment: @20Cents Yeah never mind. You really don't understand how JSON works. I suggest you find some tutorial on google because you're missing the point.

Comment: Why don't you just explain or guide me based on the thread? I think that definitely works better than find some other tutorial on google :)

Comment: Because 1st your question is too broad. There are several things that you're not doing properly. 2nd it's an off topic question. 3rd you aren't familiar with the technology you're trying to use so this discussion will lead nowhere. 4th if you really read json tutorials you will find that this is really easy to understand and that you're asking a "noob" question.